# $_POST request doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've made an post request on an inline edit screen for my website. But when i click on the submit button, nothing happend. I tried it before with an html tag but also that doesn't work.

Maybe i look at the wrong way. Can someone help with this issue. thanks a lot!

The submit button is on the top of the form.

```
<a href="" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()"><li class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></li></a>
```

Form tag

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Example input

```
<input class="edit-input-door" type="text" name="door_sale" value="<?php echo $event['door_sale']; ?>" />
```

Problem:
The submit doesn't post, so when i click on my submit button. nothing happend. He only refresh the page but post nothing.

Whole code:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="root-nav">
  <ul>
    <a href="" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()"><li class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
<span class="date-lg__ad">&euro; <input class="edit-input-door" type="text" name="door_sale" value="<?php echo $event['door_sale']; ?>" /></span>
```

Solution:

```
<button type="submit"><li class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></li></button>
```

Thanks a lot again!

Comment: "doesn't work" is just too vague.  What errors do you get in the browser console?  Where's your server-side method?

Comment: The hole submit doesn't work, he doesn't post the data, so i get nothing. also nothing in the console.log(0

Comment: Post server side code to fetch the data.

Comment: @LucaKiebel The target is the page it self. So by every other code i use the same way. But by this it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you edit your answer so that we can see the whole significant code ?

Comment: Can you confirm you do have jquery included in the page and running ok?

Comment: Where's the `button type=submit` ?  Is it inside the `form` element?  You seems to have two submit buttons, is that intended?

Comment: @freedomn-m the Jquery is running, but i've tried it now with a button html, and thats working for now, but i want it in jquery.

Comment: Can you see the request being made in the browser network tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="target">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<a href="#" id="other"><li class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></li></a>

<script>
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).submit();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

// Try this

```
 <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()"><li class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true">Click here</li></a>

<form id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  // your stuff

</form>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the a tag's default event prevent the onclick funciton , use the following instead :

```
<a href="javascript:$(this).closest('form').submit()"><li class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></li></a>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the script doesn't load.